# How to store the result of an async method in a .NET ConcurrentDictionary when calling GetOrAdd?

Tags: c#, async-await, concurrentdictionary

I have a `private ConcurrentDictionary` that is a simple lookup table of some DB keys.

I'm trying to leverage the `ConcurrentDictionary` so that it will only do one call to the db when 2+ requests to the same line of code, are made at the same time. (Which is why i'm using a `ConcurrentDictionary`.)

How can I do this please?

This is what I was *trying* to do .. but I think it's storing the `Task` in the dictionary ... not the *result* of the task....

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task<int>> _myKeys = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task<int>>();

...

private async Task<int> DoStuffAsync(string key)
{
   // do stuff here.

   return await _myKeys.GetOrAdd(key,
                                 async k => await _db.GetId(k)
                                                     .ConfigureAwait(false))
                       .ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Notice my method signature and what I'm returning. Is it better to return an `int` and not a `Task<int>` and then somehow refactor my db call to still be async .. but .. better?

Comment: What's wrong with storing a task in the dictionary?

Comment: People who are voting to close or downvoting, please explain why, to improve the Q.

Comment: @StephenCleary I wasn't sure if this was a good or bad thing. It felt like a _heavy_ object to store, when the result would just be an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

[`GetOrAdd` does not guarantee that the delegate will be called only once when it's called from multiple threads at the same time with the same value:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677(v=vs.110).aspx)

> If you call GetOrAdd simultaneously on different threads, *addValueFactory* may be called multiple times, but its key/value pair might not be added to the dictionary for every call.

This can be also seen in [the implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,2f8bcdfbad10304f):

```
TValue resultingValue;
if (TryGetValue(key, out resultingValue))
{
    return resultingValue;
}
TryAddInternal(key, valueFactory(key), false, true, out resultingValue);
return resultingValue;
```

So, to do about as good a job as `GetOrAdd()`, you can do something like (input checking omitted):

```
public static async Task<TValue> GetOrAddAsync<TKey, TValue>(
    this ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
    TKey key, Func<TKey, Task<TValue>> valueFactory)
{
    TValue resultingValue;
    if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out resultingValue))
    {
        return resultingValue;
    }
    return dictionary.GetOrAdd(key, await valueFactory(key));
}
```

If the requirement to not call the delegate twice at the same time is just a performance optimization, this should be sufficient.

If it's required for correctness of your code, then even `GetOrAdd` is not sufficient and you will need to use additional synchronization.

Comment: I suspect this is worse than the OP's code for typical cases: in your version, suppose the task takes five seconds, and after three seconds, another task calls `GetOrAddAsync` for the same key. In your code, this is guaranteed to start a new task. In the OP's code, it's extremely likely to re-use the existing task. Yes, you're right that the OP's code doesn't guarantee anything, but it does make it so much more likely that I'd go with the OP's version.

Comment: @hvd You're right. I was working under the assumption that you don't want to store `Task`s in the dictionary.