# Can an .NET ConcurrentDictionary GetOrAdd method call an async method?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, concurrentdictionary

I'm looking at using a `ConcurrentDictionary` to hold some cached data, which comes from a slow source (eg. a database).

The call to the database is `async`. So, is it possible to have the concurrent dictionary call an async method if the item doesn't exist in the dictionary?

for example:

```
const int userId = 1;
var cachedUsers = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Task<User>>();
var user = await cachedUsers.GetOrAdd(userId, val => GetSlowDbResultAsync(userId, cancellationToken));
```

so what that pseduo code above is trying to do is say:

- does User #1 exist in the C-Dict?
- Yes, ok, use that.
- No, grab user #1 from Db and stick it in the cache.

So - by putting the `Task<User>` into the concurrent-dictionary's 'value' (for a key/value):

- is that ok?
- does the code I wrote above, an acceptable use of this or have I just abused everything that is sacred with async/await/c#

---

Notes:

This question is [inspired from my question on twitter](https://twitter.com/jonskeet/status/925179370234245120).
This is similar to a [previous question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40077513/how-to-store-the-result-of-an-async-method-in-a-net-concurrentdictionary-when-c) but didn't get much traction.

Comment: If you wrap this up in a GetAsync method (so that the clients need not understand the implementation), you should be fine, I think. On the first hit, you'll await the database call, and on the second (for the same user id), you'll await the completed task. It seems fine to me.

Comment: Why did you choose `ConcurrentDictionary`? I hope you are not using async hoping it will speed things up.

Comment: See marked duplicate. Its answer uses exactly the technique you're asking about. It works fine, assuming the rest of your code is written to accommodate it.

Answer (score -4):

How about try to write an extension method, something like:

```
class Extension
{
    public static User Get(this ConcurrentDictionary<int, User> conDict, int userID)
    {
        User user = null;
        if (!conDict.TryGetValue(userID, out user))
        {
            user = GetSlowDbResultAsync(userId, cancellationToken)
           conDict.TryAdd(userID, user);
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

more information about extension method, please check with this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @sean what happens if two requests BOTH do TryGetValue at the same time, both return false .... :) We then do 2x slow db calls, next?